# Parsing out a field in MS Access that is CSV (JSON) data

Tags: sql, json, excel, parsing, ms-access

I have a CSV data file that I load into MS Access.  No problem doing that. I’ve got it all loaded.

My issue is that one of the records in the file contains a field that contains CSV data (JSON data) which is line item invoice data (ProductData) and it may contain up to 25 line items.

What I’m trying to do is parse out that field into multiple records in a different table all related by the number after “500” which is the transaction number.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this in Microsoft Access PLEASE?

#### Sample data:

```
500,3,30600052763,30128903358,"{""type"": ""reportingData"", ""merStoreId"": ""8135001"", ""productData"": [{""productCode"": ""001"", ""totalAmount"": ""20.00"", ""quantity"": ""16.000"", ""unitPrice"": ""1.25"", ""tax1Amount"": ""6.22""}, {""productCode"": ""102"", ""totalAmount"": ""14.00"", ""quantity"": ""1.000"", ""unitPrice"": ""14.00""}, {""productCode"": ""963"", ""totalAmount"": ""1.00"", ""quantity"": ""1.000"", ""unitPrice"": ""1.00"", ""tax1Amount"": ""0.00""}]}"
```

I’ve attached a sample of how I would like the table to look based on transaction number 3 above:

```
Tbl500                                      
Transaction Number  Second Field    Third Field Type            MerStoreID  ProductCode TotalAmount Quantity    UnitPrice   Tax1Amount  Tax2Amount
3                   30600052763     0128903358  reportingData   8135001     001         20.00       16.000      1.25        6.22    
3                   30600052763     30128903358 reportingData   8135001     102         14.00       1.000       14.00       
3                   30600052763     30128903358 reportingData   8135001     963         1.00        1.000       1.00        0.00
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is some code that takes the text file, imports the data and tidies it up a bit, then splits it into an array of variable length. It then loops this array, and adds the data to the table, using the presence of "productCode" to detect if it is a new record:

```
Sub sGetJSONData()
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rsData As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim intFile As Integer
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim astrData() As String
    Dim intLoop1 As Integer
    Set db = DBEngine(0)(0)
    Set rsData = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblJSON WHERE 1=2;")
    strFile = "C:\test\json.txt"
    intFile = FreeFile
    Open strFile For Input As intFile
    Do
        Erase astrData
        Line Input #intFile, strInput
        strInput = Replace(strInput, Chr(34) & Chr(34), "")
        strInput = Replace(strInput, "productData: [{", "")
        strInput = Replace(strInput, "{productCode", "productCode")
        strInput = Left(strInput, Len(strInput) - 4)
        strInput = Replace(strInput, "}", "")
        strInput = Replace(strInput, ", ", ",")
        astrData = Split(strInput, ",")
        With rsData
            .AddNew
            !TransactionNumber = astrData(1)
            !SecondField = astrData(2)
            !ThirdField = astrData(3)
            !Type = Mid(astrData(4), 9)
            !ProductCode = Mid(astrData(6), 13)
            !MerStoreID = Mid(astrData(5), 13)
            For intLoop1 = 7 To UBound(astrData)
                If Left(astrData(intLoop1), 11) = "totalAmount" Then !TotalAmount = Mid(astrData(intLoop1), 14)
                If Left(astrData(intLoop1), 8) = "quantity" Then !Quantity = Mid(astrData(intLoop1), 11)
                If Left(astrData(intLoop1), 9) = "unitPrice" Then !UnitPrice = Mid(astrData(intLoop1), 12)
                If Left(astrData(intLoop1), 10) = "tax1Amount" Then !Tax1Amount = Mid(astrData(intLoop1), 13)
                If Left(astrData(intLoop1), 10) = "tax2Amount" Then !Tax2Amount = Mid(astrData(intLoop1), 13)
                If Left(astrData(intLoop1), 11) = "productCode" Then
                    .Update
                    .AddNew
                    !TransactionNumber = astrData(1)
                    !SecondField = astrData(2)
                    !ThirdField = astrData(3)
                    !Type = Mid(astrData(4), 9)
                    !ProductCode = Mid(astrData(intLoop1), 13)
                    !MerStoreID = Mid(astrData(5), 13)
                End If
            Next intLoop1
            .Update
        End With
    Loop Until EOF(intFile)
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    rsData.Close
    Set rsData = Nothing
   Reset
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "sGetJSONData", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

Regards,